# Smali Method change long parameter

Tags: java, smali

I am starting to learn a little bit of changing java code with smali. I got an application where I want to change the percentage of a battery.

> .method public setPercentage(J)V
>
> .registers 3
>
> .line 1    iput-wide p1, p0,
> Lcom/battery/view/Base;->e:J
>
> return-void .end method

Is there a way to change the parameter of the long value to 100 ? I appreciate every help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For instance (non static) methods, `p0` is like `this` and starting at `P1` you have the method parameters. So you can change the first and only parameter in this case like this:

```
.method public setPercentage(J)V

.registers 3

#100 in hexadecimal is 0x64
const-wide/16 p1, 0x64

.line 1 iput-wide p1, p0, Lcom/battery/view/Base;->e:J

return-void

.end method
```